# How can I make a html canvas "scroll" indefinitely?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas element that automatically fills the entire browser window of the client when loaded. On it you can draw with the mouse, like in the result of any "make a drawing board"-tutorial out there. What I want to do however is to make it so that if you move the mouse to any extreme of the canvas (or maybe select a certain "move"-tool, you can drag the canvas in any direction you'd like), it scrolls. In particular, I want it to be possible to in theory scroll forever, so I can't really pre-generate, I have to generate "more canvas" on the fly. Does any one have any idea on how to do this?

If it helps, this is the client-side javascript right now: (the html is just a canvas-tag)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    init();
});

function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
      , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
      , width = window.innerWidth
      , height = window.innerHeight;

    // Sets the canvas size to be the same as the browser size
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    // Binds mouse and touch events to functions
    $(canvas).bind({
        'mousedown':  startDraw,
        'mousemove':  draw,
        'mouseup':    stopDraw,
    });
};

// Triggered on mousedown, sets draw to true and updates X, Y values.
function startDraw(e) {
    this.draw = true;
    this.X = e.pageX;
    this.Y = e.pageY;
};

// Triggered on mousemove, strokes a line between this.X/Y and e.pageX/Y
function draw(e) {
    if(this.draw) {
        with(ctx) {
            beginPath();
            lineWidth = 4;
            lineCap = 'round';
            moveTo(this.X, this.Y);
            lineTo(e.pageX, e.pageY);
            stroke();
        }
        this.X = e.pageX;
        this.Y = e.pageY;
    }
};

// Triggered on mouseup, sets draw to false
function stopDraw() {
    this.draw = false;
};
```

Comment: Did you try just setting a variable to save the X and Y scroll values and then just adding it to the coordinates of the whatever that you'll draw?

Comment: Did you ever get a working version of this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a canvas infinite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589304/make-a-canvas-infinite)

Answer (score 2):

The canvas element uses real memory of your computer, so there is no infinite canvas which scrolls forever. But, you may simulate this behavior using a virtual canvas. Just record the xy coords captured by draw() into an array and calculate a new center of the virtual canvas if the mouse touches the border. Then filter out the xy coords which fit into center +- screen size and draw them.

However, the array recording the xy coords can not grow infinitely and the filter code will get slower over the size of the array. Are 10,000 points enough?

More optimized code will turn the mouse coords into splines and saves only points needed to redraw the (smoothed) path of the mouse.

Comment: >The canvas element uses real memory of your computer, so there is no infinite canvas which scrolls forever.
Yeah, I understand that. Right now I send every drawn line with socket.io to a node.js-server, so it could potentially be stored server side. What I meant by pre rendering was that once the user started scrolling/moving in one direction, the client would request data on what was drawn in that direction earlier and draw it right before it comes in to view.

Comment: You have a solution once you set upper limits to width and height of your virtual canvas.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Right now I have no virtual canvas at all, a user can draw in the space that he has in his browser window, that's it. Do you mean I should abstract the coordinates in some way, and calculate the offset from the "real" canvas?

Comment: Yes, once you say the virtual canvas has e.g. 10,000 x 10,000 pixel you'll avoid a lot of headache.