# Make a canvas infinite

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently using a canvas on which I drew some areas of interest. They consist in squares and can be moved by a mouse click (i.e : a selected area will center on my cursor position everytime I click on the canvas).

My current problem is that I would like to add the following feature:
When I click near the edge of the canvas (either left or right), **if a portion of the square is off-canvas**, I want this off-canvas portion to appear at the opposite edfe.

Example:
If I click near the right edge of the canvas, the hidden portion should appear on the left.

To be honest, I don't have any clue on how to do this properly. It seems to me that it requires a really heavy solution (with a lot of loops).

Your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend posting what you have so far so that at least people can see what might work and what might not. It's hard to troubleshoot with no code at all.

Comment: You need to draw everything that overlaps the edge at least twice (once for each side it is visible) if it is in a corner an thus will be visible in every other corner you need to draw it 4 times once for each corner

Comment: Do you mean an infinite panorama? Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263954/make-a-bitmap-wrap-around-the-canvas-for-infinite-scrolling/20273738#20273738).

Comment: You can use the library called TiledCanvas
It provides interfaces to zoom and move. And draw in an infinite space using all the canvas apis. It does require that you tell where you are drawing. https://github.com/Squarific/TiledCanvas This has the advantage that you don't have to do things like zooming or moving yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple way to do this is

You have an object with width height, x,and y

```
obj = { x :?, y : ?, w : ? , h: ?}
```

You draw it

```
ctx.fillRect(obj.x, obj.y, obj.w, obj.h);
```

You have the screen/canvas size

```
canW = ?;
canH = ?;
```

When you draw the object check if it is touching the right edge. If so draw it again on the left side

```
if(obj.x + obj.w > canW){
   ctx.fillRect(obj.x - canW,obj.y, obj.w, obj.h);
```

Now as you are on the left side check that it's not on the bottom edge if it is draw it again at the top

```
   if(obj.y + obj.h > canH){
       ctx.fillRect(obj.x - canW, obj.y - canH, obj.w, obj.h);
   }
```

}

And the same for the bottom, But ass you have already done the top left in the above render you only need check this time for the bottom top

```
if(obj.y + obj.h > canH){
   ctx.fillRect(obj.x, obj.y - canH, obj.w, obj.h);
}
```

And you are done.

Demo shows a random infinite scrolling colored box scene.

```js
var onResize;
function display(){  //
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    if(array.length === 0){
        addRandomObjects();
    }
    // move the scene;
    offsetDX += (Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random())/3 -0.5;
    offsetDY += (Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random())/3 -0.5;
    offsetDX = Math.max(-4,Math.min(4,offsetDX));
    offsetDY = Math.max(-4,Math.min(4,offsetDY));
    offsetX += offsetDX;
    offsetY += offsetDY;
    offsetX = ((offsetX % w) + w) % w;
    offsetY = ((offsetY % h) + h) % h;
  
    // draw the scene;
    drawObjects();
    
}
var offsetX = 0;
var offsetY = 0;
var offsetDX = 0;
var offsetDY = 0;

var drawObjects = function(){
    var ox = offsetX;  // get the offset
    var oy = offsetY;
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){ // do each object
        var a = array[i];
        var x = (a.x + ox)%w;
        var y = (a.y + oy)%h;
        ctx.fillStyle = a.col;   
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,a.w,a.h); // draw it
        if(x+a.w > w){  // if touching right edge draw again at left
            ctx.fillRect(x-w,y,a.w,a.h);
            if(y+a.h > h){
                ctx.fillRect(x-w,y-h,a.w,a.h);
            }
              
        }
        if(y+a.h > h){ // if touching bottom draw again at top
            ctx.fillRect(x,y-h,a.w,a.h);
        }
    }

}

var array = [];

var addRandomObjects = function(){
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        var hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
        array.push({
            x: Math.random() * w,
            y : Math.random() * h,
            w : Math.max(50,Math.random() * (w * h * 0.0004)),
            h : Math.max(80,Math.random() * (w * h * 0.0004)),
            col: "hsla("+hue+",100%,50%,0.5)",
        })
    }
}

var onResize = function(){
    array = [];
}






/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js begin **/
//==================================================================================================
// The following code is boilerplate code that provides me with a standard interface to various forums.
// It provides a mouse interface, a full screen canvas, and some global often used variable  
// like canvas, ctx, mouse, w, h (width and height), globalTime
// This code is not intended to be part of the answer unless specified and has been formated to reduce
// display size. It should not be used as an example of how to write a canvas interface.
// By Blindman67
const U = undefined;const RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 100;
var w,h,cw,ch,canvas,ctx,mouse,createCanvas,resizeCanvas,setGlobals,globalTime=0,resizeCount = 0; 
var L = typeof log === "function" ? log : function(d){ console.log(d); }
createCanvas = function () { var c,cs; cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style; cs.position = "absolute"; cs.top = cs.left = "0px"; cs.zIndex = 1000; document.body.appendChild(c); return c;}
resizeCanvas = function () {
    if (canvas === U) { canvas = createCanvas(); } canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.height = window.innerHeight; ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    if (typeof setGlobals === "function") { setGlobals(); } if (typeof onResize === "function"){ resizeCount += 1; setTimeout(debounceResize,RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME);}
}
function debounceResize(){ resizeCount -= 1; if(resizeCount <= 0){ onResize();}}
setGlobals = function(){ cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2; ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2; }




resizeCanvas(); 
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas); 

function update(timer){ // Main update loop
    globalTime = timer;
    display();  // call demo code
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);

/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That was EXACTLY what I was looking for. It is actually a bit more complex due to the nature of the application we are building, but the mecanism is the simplest I've come across.

Thank you very much, again. I will have to store some information in addition but it will work :)